# Define a function to sort a list of strings by the first 4 characters of the string? (Without using sort function)

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list of strings like this

```
source_1 = [
"2012 18  B",
"2015 19  B",
"2007 948 D",
"2018 179 C"]
```

I want to define a function (without using the python sort method) to sort these strings so that the output will be:

```
    source_1 = [
"2007 948 D",
"2012 18  B",
"2015 19  B",
"2018 179 C"]
```

So far I have come up with this but it's too inefficient?:

```
def sorttimestamp(arr):   
sorted = []
for s in arr:
        restof = s[-6:]
        timestamp = s[:10]

        sorted.append(timestamp)
        for i in range(len(sorted)):
                for j in range(i + 1, len(sorted)):
                        if sorted[i] > sorted[j]:
                                sorted[i], sorted[j] = sorted[j], sorted[i]
return sorted
```

Comment: What is your aversion to using the `sort()` function?

Comment: `range` is a built-in function, so is `len`

Comment: I mean the sort() and sorted()

Comment: Sounds like a school assignment where you are required to implement a sorting algorithm yourself. If you find your current implementation too inefficient, then what have you done to improve it, based on what your school has taught you, and what's preventing you from making an improvement happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with key function as you like:

```
source_1 = [
"2012 18  B",
"2012 11  B",
"2015 19  B",
"2015 19  A",
"2007 100 D",
"2007 948 D",
"2018 179 C",
"2018 179 D"]

res = sorted(source_1, key=lambda x: (x.split()[0], x.split()[1], x.split()[2]))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['2007 100 D',
 '2007 948 D',
 '2012 11  B',
 '2012 18  B',
 '2015 19  A',
 '2015 19  B',
 '2018 179 C',
 '2018 179 D']
```

Comment: I said in the question without using built in function

Comment: @nomoresky, edited answer, without built-in `sort` function.

Comment: I can't see your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a built-in function, try out [quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) to reduce your time complexity from O(n^2) to O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the insertion sort algorithm.
It works best on relatively small datasets.

I'd still be using the builtin sorted() function, though, if efficiency is what's needed. It has a worst case complexity of O(n*log(n)), iirc, while this insertion sort I am proposing features a linear complexity at best, but a quadratic one on average / worst cases:

```
def insertion_sort(arr):
    """Algorithm main function."""
    # iterate through elements 1 through n-1
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        temp = arr[i]
        j = i - 1

        # make room for temp
        # for descending order sorting, replace < with > below
        while j >= 0 and temp < arr[j]:
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j]
            j -= 1        
        # place temp at its correct place
        arr[j + 1] = temp    
    return arr
```